# App not listed in search results for specific device but listed as compatible in Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

A user of our App mailed us today and let us know, that our App is not visible in search results for his device. Even in the Web View he cannot install the App on this device ( but on others ).

He owns an Sony Xperia Z3 Compact (D5803). In the Google Play Developer Console  - Section "APK" and "Supported Devices" the Device is Listed and checked green.

Where and how can i find out why he can´t install it and what i can do that it is possible in future?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your app to Google Play, you can select the countries in which to distribute your app under **Pricing and Distribution**. The app will then be available to users in only the countries you select, so that may be the country of that user not included in those countries.